# $PORT usage for Docker deployment to Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, port

Trying to deploy docker image to Heroku.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
```

I've built this Dockerfile and when run locally using port 80 it works as expected.

I understand that Heroku requires $PORT, but I'm unsure where to apply this.

The message I get in the logs after pushing and releasing this to Heroku is:

```
2020-07-31T15:14:36.016276+00:00 app[web6.1]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
2020-07-31T15:14:36.016304+00:00 app[web6.1]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
```

New to Heroku and Docker so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -3):

EXPOSE command is not supported while deploying Docker image to Heroku.
According to Heroku Docs:

> While EXPOSE can be used for local testing, it is not supported in Heroku’s container runtime. Instead, your web process/code should get the $PORT environment variable.

Please refer [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime) for more information about Docker deployment.
Hope this will resolve your issue.